# Installing Gradle manually on Intellij

Tags: windows, gradle, intellij-idea, manual

How do I install downloaded Gradle for Windows OS on Intellij? I've tried to unzip the folder then copying it in a Gradle folder I created on Local Disk C, I've also added the path in the Enviroment Variables but still not working.

Comment: `but still not working.` - what does not work? Please add details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new project follow these steps:

1. Launch IntelliJ and select the "New project" option, you should see Gradle appearing on the left hand side option bar
2. Specify the JDK and maybe some Frameworks